# What does a slash do to a string with a dot in php?

Tags: php

If `$GLOBALS['filefolder'] = 13.pressrum`
How come

```
$filefolder = '/'+$GLOBALS['filefolder'];
echo $filefolder
```

output
13

When

```
$filefolder = $GLOBALS['filefolder'];
echo $filfolder
```

outputs
13.pressrum

Comment: You're using `+` to concatenate. It should be `.`.

Comment: Read the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator `+` is numeric / mathematical in PHP.
So `'/'+$GLOBALS['filefolder'];` is equal to `0+13` in your case (php casts both to integer) which actually is 13.

To concatenate use `.`

```
$filefolder = '/' . $GLOBALS['filefolder'];
echo $filefolder
```

Answer (score 4):

A `+` adds two numbers as in 1+1. So if you use it to concatenate two strings, they get converted to integers internally and thus the result is 13. A dot (`.`) concatenates two string. So you have to write `$filefolder = '/'.$GLOBALS['filefolder'];`

You probably confused it with JavaScript, where + is used to concatenate strings (and also for adding numbers, but that's another topic...).

Answer (score 2):

The + operator in php is the sum. If you sum '/' + "13.pressrum", both will be casted to integer.

You should use . to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a mathematical operator, so PHP tries to find numbers in `/` and `13.pressrum` it only finds the 13 so you get the result of `0 + 13`, which is `13`.

I guess what you wanted to do is concatenate the strings, try this:

```
$filefolder = '/'.$GLOBALS['filefolder'];
echo $filefolder
```

It should output `/13.pressrum`.